# Driver selection misbehaving in Windows 10 2004

Tags: drivers, xbox360, windows-10-v2004

Today I updated my Windows 10 to the 2004 version. After that I sat down to play some FIFA, so I connected my wireless receiver for XBOX 360 Controller. Nothing popped up. This is quite normal. I generally need to head over to `Device Manager` then find the `Unknown Device`:
[Device on plug in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Btm.png)

Then I right-click on it, do Update Driver > Browse my computer for Drivers > Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer > Xbox 360 Peripherals > Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version 10.0.19041.1 [06-12-2019]

I hit "Next", and it says "Windows has successfully updated the drivers".
Until now, whenever I followed this procedure, the device was then labeled as Wireless Reciever for Xbox 360 in the Device Manager and I could connect my controller and start playing.

But now, when I hit "Close" on the dialog box, the device is still marked as `Unknown Device` in the Device Manager: [Device after selecting the driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN0v6.png)

Here is the properties tab of the device after selecting the driver: [Unknown Device Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nZ3H.png). Clicking on the `Driver Details` button, I get a prompt saying

> No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device.

I'm not exactly sure what is causing this issue, the only difference since the last time I used it (2 days ago) is that now I have updated to Windows 10 2004.

Comment: Look to see if you have Core Isolation enabled.Disable that    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNX2GDzfT6A